# How to OCR this subtitle?

Tags: linux, ocr

Is there any Linux OCR tool that can extract this subtitle without having to train a LSTM? Language is Portuguese. Some image cropping and python coding is acceptable...

I could not find a Tesseract command line that works.

[image: movie screenshot]

Comment: Well I tried to use existing Tesseract based OCR software to extract text from frames extracted from a video without training the program and the result is really horrible, better train the Tesseract program before you expect it to do anything useful.

Comment: But to train Tesseract I need to already have the OCRd text.

Comment: I am sure you can extract the text by hand... Just think about it, programs are designed to automate a specific process, however as of today you still have to write the programs manually first, there is no easy way AFAIK...

Comment: So, why would I train Tesseract after I have extracted it by hand?

Comment: Good question, you need to train it first, and after you have trained it you can use the program to extract Portuguese subtitles from other videos reliably, but unfortunately not the first one, it's like gravity, it needs a little push to set things in motion.